# Should a switch / if-elseif-else function have a default case which returns null if no case matched and handled in the handler?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Case 1 (throws error is no switch case matched):

```
function getColorName(c) {
  switch(c) {
      case Color.Red:
          return 'red, red wine';
      case Color.Green:
          return 'greenday';
      case Color.Blue:
          return "Im blue, daba dee daba";
      default:
          throw new Error('error');
  }
}

getColorName(Color.Yellow); // this results in an error thrown
```

Case 2 (the default case returns null and that's handled in the caller):

```
function getColorName(c) {
  switch(c) {
      case Color.Red:
          return 'red, red wine';
      case Color.Green:
          return 'greenday';
      case Color.Blue:
          return "Im blue, daba dee daba";
      default:
          return null;
  }
}

if (getColorName(Color.Yellow)) {
  // do stuff here 
}
```

This might not be the perfect example. However, **the goal of the question is to understand what is the approach which covers as many use cases as possible while avoiding excessive complexity when a switch logic exist?**

While out of the scope of the question, as a means of clarification of possible use cases, the switch would be implemented either

1. with a `switch` (like above)
2. as a `if-elseif-else` function (if the switch cases are complex or there are only few cases)

**if-elseif-else example** (for reference):

```
function getColorName(c) {
    if (Color.Red) { 
       return 'red, red wine';
    }
    else if (Color.Green) {
       //... 
    }
    // etc. (--cut--)
    else {
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228287/returning-null-or-a-empty-value-throw-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred practice is to throw an **exception** and not return **null** and have the **caller** function determine the next steps. Your **called** function should only worry about the data input it gets, whether it has suitable information basis the data input to do its job and either return a valid response basis the input or let the **caller** function know it can't process the input.

In your example returning a **null** would mean your caller function would have to have null handling with another conditional loop and then basis that either return null further to its own caller function or do something else. This makes the code quite cumbersive whilst specific exceptions can be easily propogated upwards as needed and prove quite useful for logging and fixing issues.